# Find and replace texts in all files from the text file input using Python in Notepad++

Tags: python, replace, find, notepad++

I'm using Notepad ++ to do a find and replacement function. Currently I have a a huge numbers of text files. I need to do a replacement for different string in different file. I want do it in batch. For example.

I have a folder that has the huge number of text file. I have another text file that has the strings for find and replace in order

Text1 Text1-corrected

Text2 Text2-corrected

I have a small script that do this replacement only for the opened files in Notepad++. For achieving this I'm using **python script** in **Notepad++**. The code is as follows.

```
 with open('C:/replace.txt') as f:
 for l in f:
    s = l.split()
    editor.replace(s[0], s[1])
```

In simple words, the find and replace function should fetch the input from a file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('replace.txt') as f:
    replacements = [tuple(line.split()) for line in f]
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        contents = f.read()
        for old, new in replacements:
            contents = contents.replace(old, new)
        f.write(contents)
```

Read replacements into a list of tuples, then go through each file, and read the contents into memory, do the replacements, then write it back.  I think the files get overwritten properly, but you might want to double check.

Comment: Thank you for the response Patrick. Where to set the source folder path? It is not mentioned in the code. Kindly help me.

Comment: The python script is "in" whatever place you run it from.  To change the directory it's in, use the `chdir` function from the `os` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#process-parameters

Comment: The code is not working. I have set the working folder and tried the code. It was not working. The error code it shows is
` for filename in filenames:
NameError: name 'filenames' is not defined`

Comment: @PradeepAugustine make a list `filenames` that contains the names of the files you want to modify.

Comment: I want all the files in its root and its sub-folder to get modified. The Final code I used is
`import os
os.chdir('c:\\Users\Prade\Desktop\Bible Format\Bible')
with open('replace.txt') as f:
    replacements = [tuple(line.split()) for line in f]
for filename in files:
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        contents = f.read()
        for old, new in replacements:
            contents = contents.replace(old, new)
        f.write(contents)`
The same error.

Comment: You need to define the `files` variable.

Comment: I just started to learn Python. I really don't know to do it. Please give it in a code format. Thank you so much for helping me till this point.

Comment: `files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']` but with the names of the files you want to modify

Comment: As stated, it has huge number of files say 5000+. It is very difficult to create such a big list. Any work around?

Comment: If all the files are in the same place, you can use the module `glob`.  Use `os.chdir` to get into the directory all these files are in, and then use `files=glob.glob('*.txt')` to get the names of all .txt files in that directory.